# Excel VBA - Why is my "Save As" not working?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA script in place so that if a cell is blank then Excel will prompt the file to be saved.

This is ensure that the template is not altered. However, when the user clicks save in the "Save As" dialogue box, the file does not save.

This is the code I am using:

```
If Worksheets("Input").Range("E2").Value = "" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.GetSaveAsFilename InitialFileName:="\\ac35542\Problem Management\Action Plans\ChangeMe.xlsm", FileFilter:="Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm),*.xlsm"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    MsgBox "Please ensure fill in the Problem Reference Number, Problem Title, and Select a Contract", vbExclamation, "PR Reference & Title"
    Worksheets("Input").Select
    Range("E2").Select
End If
```

Why is the file not saving?

Comment: `GetSaveAsFilename` just returns the path and filename that the user selected: it doesn't actually do any saving. You have to call `SaveAs` if you want to save the file.

Comment: @TimWilliams Is there any way of just displaying the "Save As" prompt so the user can same the document?

Comment: sorry, @Tim, didn't see your comment while posting an answer

Comment: `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As follow up from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195734%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

> Application.GetSaveAsFilename displays the standard Save As dialog box
>   and gets a file name from the user **without actually saving any
>   files.**.

use this one instead:

```
Dim fileSaveName
If Worksheets("Input").Range("E2").Value = "" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="\\ac35542\Problem Management\Action Plans\ChangeMe.xlsm", FileFilter:="Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm),*.xlsm")
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    If fileSaveName <> "False" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs (fileSaveName)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

    MsgBox "Please ensure fill in the Problem Reference Number, Problem Title, and Select a Contract", vbExclamation, "PR Reference & Title"
    Worksheets("Input").Select
    Range("E2").Select
End If
```

Comment: Yet another brilliant answer. However, When I run this, I get "Run-Time error '13': Type mismatch and If fileSaveName <> False Then is highlighted. If I change False to "" then it works. Will this have any impact?

Comment: @Petay87, Try to use `If fileSaveName <> "False" Then` instead (see my updated answer)

Comment: it was that line highlighted in the nice Debug yellow. But if I change it to `fileSaveName <> ""` it works without issue.

Comment: try to use `If fileSaveName <> "False" Then`

Comment: Now I understand what the `<> "False"` does, I understand the need for quotations and yes it now works with your adjusted answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's for handling situation when user press "Cancel" in "Save As" dialog box:)

Comment: I hadn't realised that clicking cancel actually calls the document "False" but still saves it. It wasn't till I tested it again that I saw the change in title. Now everything makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think Dmitry Pavliv's method is fine, but I think the "InitialFileName:="\ac35542\Problem Management\Action Plans\ChangeMe.xlsm" part makes it a little bit less dynamic.

For me, the below code worked perfectly:

```
ExportPath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FILEFILTER:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="")
'Basically, user will specify the path and give it a name and click on Save. It won't get saved until the next line though.
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (ExportPath)
```